# Let $p>0$ be a constant. Prove that if $E{|X|}^p<\infty$, then $x^pP(|X| > x)\to 0(x\to \infty)$.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

My idea is $$x^pP(|X|>x)=x^pEI(|X|>x)\le x^p E\frac{|X|^p}{x^p}I(|X|>x)\le E|X|^p<\infty$$.Then I have no idea. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Maybe of use: since $|X|>0$, you can write $E|X| = \int_0^\infty P(|X|>y)dy$, $E|X| ^p= \int_0^\infty P(|X|^p>y)dy$

Comment: The definition of expectation is $E|X|=\int_{0}^\infty |x|P(|X|>y)dy$, right?

Comment: No. Expectation is $EX = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx$. But when $X$ is non-negative, it can also be written $EX = \int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx$. Note the lack of an "x" in the integral.  It may be useful in your proof (Im not sure if its needed, but thought it worth mentioning).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the dominated convergence theorem: $x^p \mathbf{1}_{|X|>x}$ converges to $0$ as $x\to\infty$ and has an obvious integrable dominant.

Comment: I get it. How to prove the opposite situation when $x^pP(|X|>x)\to0$, then for $\forall 0<\epsilon<p$,$E|X|^{p-\epsilon}<\infty$. Thank you very much~

Comment: Ask a separate question. And don't forget to show your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^p P(|X|>x) = x^p \int_\Omega 1(|X| >x) dP \leq \int_\Omega |X|^p 1(|X|>x) dP $$

If anything in the above inequality does not make sense, feel free to ask.

Anyway, since $E|X|^p < \infty$ and $E|X|^p = \int_\Omega |X|^p dP$, it must be that

$$\int_\Omega |X|^p1(|X|>x) dP \to 0$$

as $x \to \infty$, since if it did not, then $E|X|^p$ could not be finite. But we have shown

$x^p P(|X|>x) \leq \int_\Omega |X|^p 1(|X|>x) dP $.

Hence $x^p P(|X|>p) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ also.

Comment: $\int_x^\infty dP...$ what a nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, I realise now how moronic that was to write...

Answer (score 1):

Your estimate of $x^pP(|X|>x)$ by $E\left\lvert X\right\rvert^p$ is a little bit too crude. As zhoraster suggests,  integrating the pointwise inequality 
$$
x^p\mathbf 1\{\left\lvert X\right\rvert \gt x\}\leqslant  \left\lvert X\right\rvert^p\mathbf 1\{\left\lvert X\right\rvert \gt x\}
$$
and then using the monotone convergence theorem gives the result.